# Automatic .ipa file, create using terminal script is showing error

Tags: ios, bash, terminal

I am using terminal to build the iOS application. It shows the build is successful, but .ipa file is not created.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#


#cd "${PROJDIR}"
WS_DIR="${WS_PATH}"
cd $WS_DIR/

API_TOKEN="${TESTFLIGHT_APP_TOKEN}"
TEAM_TOKEN="${TESTFLIGHT_TEAM_TOKEN}"

PROJECT_NAME="${PROJECTNAME}"
CREATED_PATH="${IPA_PATH}"
FILE_PATH=$WS_DIR/$CREATED_PATH/$PROJECT_NAME.ipa
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGN}"
BUILD_RELESE=$WS_DIR/build/Release-iphoneos/$PROJECT_NAME.app
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME="${PROVISIONING_NAME}"
LIBRARY="~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"
PROVISIONING_PROFILES="$LIBRARY/${PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME}.mobileprovision"
ZIP_FILE=$WS_DIR/$CREATED_PATH/$PROJECT_NAME.app.dSYM.zip


#Create your directory where you store ipa file.
#mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
mkdir -p $CREATED_PATH
cp "${PROVISIONING_PROFILES}" "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"


xcodebuild -project $PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME}"  -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration Release


# Create IPA file if your build is sccuessed.
# Change Path where you get the Build file and where you store you .ipa file 
# Replace your Provisioning Profiles & sign 

/bin/rm "/tmp/${PRODUCT_NAME}.ipa"
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${BUILD_RELESE}" -o "${FILE_PATH}" --sign "${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" --embed "${PROVISIONING_PROFILES}"


#Zip dsYM to upload into test flight
zip -r $ZIP_FILE $BUILD_RELESE.dSYM
#Upload Build file on TestFlight
```

Output directory: '/Users/sandeepsachan/Documents/Project/SampleTestFlighUpload/_IPA/SampleTestFlighUpload.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/var/folders/p7/4ds34y153w30y6p9dnm86mkw0000gn/T/iPf7pGVUbK'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)

Comment: Well...where is the rest of the script?

Comment: Is the variable really called `BUILD_RELESE`?

Comment: this script i am using to build application and then ipa file.

Comment: error: Unable to copy '~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/7AF28F9A-5FA0-4087-A1D5-166DA124E7F3.mobileprovision' to '/var/folders/p7/4ds34y153w30y6p9dnm86mkw0000gn/T/iPf7pGVUbK/Payload/SampleTestFlighUpload.app/embedded.mobileprovision'